# Xcode Push Notification: APNS server for production mode

Tags: xcode, notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

I'm realizing my first app with push notification. I've done all the debugging following the [Ray Wanderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)
and everything works.

Now that I'm about to proceed with the submission I would like to know what parameters I have to insert for the "live" server in production mode instead of

```
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

Hope to be clear

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the port is the same, only the host is different, it's `gateway.push.apple.com`.

> The binary interface of the production environment is available through gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195; the binary interface of the development environment is available through gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)