# Push Notification issue in IOS 8

Tags: swift

I got device token in IOS 8 devices in Adhoc mode, but after the app published on AppStore, I am not able to receive device tokens for devices.

Code is as:

```
if application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications()
    {

       UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        // iOS 8 Notifications
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil));
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    }
```

and other callbacks methods has also been implemented.

Please help what the problem is and any solution for it.Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the production services, remember when you are developing you use a develop services but when the app is in the AppStore you need to use the production services..

Comment: [see link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399356/xcode-push-notification-apns-server-for-production-mode) this could be issue. Use production url server side.

Comment: Thanks..Yes I am using AirNotifier server for Push Notification and had all the production certificates i.e .pem and privatekey. Yet the notification is not coming.

Comment: Also on IOS 9 application is running fine with notifications coming.Only on IOS 8 problem is coming.